# Change length of JTextPane array

Tags: arrays, swing, dynamic, arraylist, jtextpane

I want to create an array of JTextPane that it's size and values change through out the execution of my program, such as arrayList.
Is it possible to do it similar to an arrayList?

I've two JFrames. In the first frame I have a JList with about 100 items.
After selecting any of the items I want to paste them per Drag&Drop to the second frame.
The second frame has a GridBagLayout, hence I want to paste each selected item to an 
array of JTextPane after dropping the items.

I want to use JTextPane because I want to format the selected text.

Comment: *"I want to create an array of JTextPane.."*  Why?  What is the application feature you are trying to implement with this array?

Comment: why you are not using arraylist?

Comment: @ Arijit: as I mentioned in my question, I need JTextPane cause I want to format the text. Therefore, I need something like an arrayList for JTextPane

Comment: Post a MCVE for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

now I found a solution and my code seems to work:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RefreshPanel {

private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JTextPane [] textPane;
private JScrollPane scrollbar;
private ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
private JButton newItem = new JButton("new");
private int counter=0;
private GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();

RefreshPanel() {        
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(gbl);                       
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));

    scrollbar = new JScrollPane(panel);

    addButtonListener();        

    createFrame();
} //constructor

public void addButtonListener() {
    newItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            arrayList.add("data");
            textPane = new JTextPane[arrayList.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++) {
                textPane[i]=new JTextPane();
                textPane[i].setText((String) arrayList.get(i));
                addComponent(panel, gbl, textPane[i], 1, counter, 1, 1,1,1);
                counter++;
            }               
        }           
    });
}

public void addComponent(Container cont, 
         GridBagLayout gbl, 
         Component c,
         int x, int y,
         int width, int height,
         double weightx, double weighty) {

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = x; gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridwidth = width; gbc.gridheight = height;
    gbc.weightx = weightx; gbc.weighty = weighty;
    gbl.setConstraints( c, gbc );
    cont.add( c );
}
public void createFrame() {
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(scrollbar);
    frame.add(newItem);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
    new RefreshPanel();
}       
}
```

But there is a little something which won't work: the items appears when I change the size of the frame, but I don't know why... any ideas?

thanks!